# Resizing function appends elements multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a bit of code that needs to detect scrollbars on resize and load. This is straightforward enough, the issue arises when I run the `append()` function, it appends the elements over and over again.

Below is the jQuery I am using (the demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dirtyharry/ampnL30w/3/))

```
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
    return this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.width();
}

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var tableWidth =  $("table").width();
    var wrapper = "<div class='top-scroll'><div class='inner'></div></div>";
    var instruction = "<span class='instructions'>Scroll left to see more information</span>";

    // This sets the overflow message and a placeholder width to match the table
    if( $('.no-overflow').hasScrollBar()){
        $('.no-overflow').before(wrapper);
        $('.top-scroll').before(instruction);
        $('.top-scroll').children().attr("style", "width:" + tableWidth + "px;");
    }

    // This synchronises the scrollbars
    $(".top-scroll").scroll(function(){
        $(".no-overflow")
            .scrollLeft($(".top-scroll").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".no-overflow").scroll(function(){
        $(".top-scroll")
            .scrollLeft($(".no-overflow").scrollLeft());
    });
}).resize();
```

I'd like the append to only happen once and also remove when there are no scrollbars present.

Comment: have you tried `.one("resize")` instead of `.on("resize")` ? it only runs one time that way ..

Comment: Resize will run every time you resize, so when you drag the window to resize it runs multiple times. What you can do is add a class to whatever is changing and check for that class to decide if you need to do something or not. This way you have the option of removing the class when conditions meet and reapplying when needed

Answer (score 0):

To check for scrollbars:

```
if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
    //There is a vertical scrollbar
} else {
    //There is no vertical scrollbar
}
```

To only create one `.top-scroll`:

```
if( $('.no-overflow').hasScrollBar() && $('.top-scroll').length < 1) { // Check .top-scroll doesn't exists currently
    $('.no-overflow').before(wrapper);
    $('.top-scroll').before(instruction);
    $('.top-scroll').children().attr("style", "width:" + tableWidth + "px;");
}
```

I would also put your 3 variable declarations within your `if` statement so they will only be set if the statement is true. Unless of course you are using them elsewhere.